# C and OpenMP: pointer to shared read-only data slows down execution

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

This is my situation, I have an array of pointers that point to arrays of some data... Let's say:

```
    Data** array = malloc ( 100 * sizeof(Data*));
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) array[i] = malloc (20 * sizeof(Data);
```

Inside a parallel region, I make some operations that use that data. For instance:

```
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) firstprivate(array)
    {
         function(array[0], array[omp_get_thread_num()];
    }
```

The first parameter is read-only but is the same along all threads...

The problem is that if I use as the first parameter a diferent block of data, i.e.: array[omp_get_thread_num()+1], each function lasts 1seg. But when I use the same block of data, array[0], *each* function call lasts 4segs.

My theory is that there is no way to know if the array[0] will be changed or not by the funciton so each thread asks for a copy and invalidate the copies that other threads have and that should explain the delay...

I tried to make a local copy of array[0] like this:

```
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) firstprivate(array)
    {
        Data* tempData = malloc(20 * sizeof(Data));
        memcpy(tempData,array[0], 20*sizeof(Data));

        function(tempData, array[omp_get_thread_num()];
    }
```

But I get the same result... It's like the thread doesn't 'release' the Data block so other threads could use it...

I have to note that the first parameter is not always array[0] so I can't use firstprivate(array[0]) in the pragma line...

Questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a way to 'release' a shared block of memory so other threads
  could use it?

It was very difficult try to make me understand so if you need further information, please let me know!

Thanks in advance... Javier

EDIT: I can't change the function declaration because it comes inside a library! (ACML)

Comment: you say the first arg is read-only, but then you say theres no way to say if it was modified. 

how many times is `function` called in total by your program? if you do memset many times, runtime will certainly be high.

Comment: I "know" that the arg will not be changed because the function is part of the ACML lib and this is how it works... What I tried to say is that the compiler/program doesn't know if it will be changed or not and that's why the other copies are being 'invalidated'

Comment: you could try this. declare data** outside the parallel region, but put `for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) array[i] = malloc (20 * sizeof(Data);` inside the par region so that every thread mallocs its own data blocks. of course `i<100` will change to something like `i<100/omp_get_num_threads()`. I am still not sure why case 2 did not work, but am interested to know the result of this.

Comment: Well... this is strange... Now i'm only doing the mallocs into a private block of memory, 'array' variable doesn't participate at all in the function call and I have the same result... I'm starting to think that it is not a memory problem but an issue with the ACML library that somehow can't handle operations in multiple threads correctly (I'm using a thread pool with nested paralelism with 8 teams with 4 threads each one)... I'll take a look at that and make more tests and I'll let you know the results... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right in your analysis that the compiler has no way to know that the pointed to array didn't change behind his back. Actually he knows that they might change, since thread `0` receives the same `array[0]` also as a modifiable argument.

So he has to have the values reloaded too often. First, you should declare your function something like

```
void function(Data const*restrict A, Data*restrict B);
```

This is telling the compiler, first, that the values in `A` can't be changed, and then that none of the pointers can be aliased by the other (or any other pointer), and so that he knows that the values in the arrays will only changed by the function itself.

For thread number `0` the assertion above wouldn't be true, the arrays `A` and `B` are actually the same. So you'd best copy `array[0]` to a common `temparray` *before* you go into the `#pragma omp parallel`, and pass that same `temparray` as a first argument to every thread:

```
Data const* tempData = memcpy(malloc(20 * sizeof(Data)), array[0], 20*sizeof(Data));

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
function(tempData, array[omp_get_thread_num()];
```

Comment: Hey Jens, Thanks for your answer!
My problem here is that the function come from a library (ACML in fact) so I can't change it's declaration... Sorry, my mistake for not tell it before...

Comment: @JaviOrtiz, so please show us the declaration of that function. If it is as I was thinking, you would in fact be stuck.

Comment: This is what my acml.h contains for one of the functions I have to use.

extern void strsm(char side, char uplo, char transa, char diag, int m, int n, float alpha, float *a, int lda, float *b, int ldb);

The parameters are "float *a" and "float *b" and none have a *const* so... I think I'm stuck with this...

Comment: @JaviOrtiz, ah, what a pitty that interface is really bad designed, if you are stuck to that interface you can't do much. One hope would be that in reallity this would be Fortran routine and somebody just translated the interface wrongly into C. You then could "cheat" by just providing your own, better, prototype, at your own risk, though.

Comment: first, maybe just keep `array` shared and not firstprivate? firstprivate only makes the double-pointer private, and not the actual data block. second, why does his case 2 - allocating a new array and memsetting it and passing it to `function` take so long?. it is truly private memory. hopefully, OP is not reporting memset in time taken.

Comment: @KVM thank you for the first advice! I'll keep in mind that!
About the 2nd part, I don't have an answer about why is taking so long... I think that maybe a thread is keeping the 'shared' block for itself and doesn't release it after it copies it. (I didn't understand the sentences "OP is not reporting memset in time taken")... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong in your analysis. If the data is not changed, imho it will not be synchronized between cores. There are two probable reasons for the slowing down.

1. The core #0 gets `function(array[0], array[0])`. You said that first parameter is read-only, but the second is not. So core #0 will change the data in `array[0]` and the CPU will have to synchronize this data between the cores all the time.
2. The second possible reason is the small size of your arrays (20 elements). What happens is that the core #1 gets a pointer to the 20-element array, and core #2 gets the pointer to array, which is probably right after the array #1 in memory. Thus there is a high probability that they lie on the same cache line. The CPU does not track changing each particular element - if it sees that elements on the same cache line are changed, it will synchronize the cache between the cores. Solution is to make each array bigger (so that after 20 elements you have unused space equal to cache size (128K? 256K?))

My guess that you have both, #1 and #2 problems in your code.